# Finding classes with spaces in XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I asked a question about XPath earlier and I tried to adapt from it for another issue I have, but it didnt work out.
Now I want to get the href value of some links, which I will iterate over later on. These links are located in a `<div class="right-body-2">`

In that div is a table and the `<a>`-Element is a child from a `<td>`-Element
There are multiple links in that `<div>`but I only need the ones with the parent `<td class="link ac">`. The spaces are a little tricky, but I found a solution (At least I think so). However, it still won't work.

```
ICollection<IWebElement> matchLinks =
phantomDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'right-body-2')]//td[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '), ' ac ')]/a/@href"));
```

Where is the error?

UPDATE:

The solution

```
//div[contains(@class,'col-lg-8')]//td[contains(@class, 'link ac')]/a/hrefs
```

gives me an empty Collection. I try to write the extracted hrefs in a RichTextBox but the box remains empty.

```
foreach (IWebElement match in matchLinks)
{
    rtb_matches.Text += match.Text + Environment.NewLine;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are multiple classes as a class cannot contain spaces in them. So your node actually has two classes: `link` and `ac`.
To find this node you can simply add several selections with `contains` functions, like so:

```
"//td[contains(@class, 'link')][contains(@class, 'ac')]"
```

or simply combine both, which is shorter but only works if order of classes  doesn't change (it very rarely does):

```
"//td[contains(@class, 'link ac')]"
```

Comment: Mh..that does not give me an error, but there is nothing in the Collection then.

Comment: @I3LaCkPeArL are you sure the page source is what you think it is? maybe there are no `<td class="link ac">` at all? I've tested the xpath and it's definitely working.

Comment: I worked myself through the page source with developer tools. The class is there for sure. Maybe my output is wrong because it is an attribute value and not a text?

Comment: @I3LaCkPeArL try outputting/printing what PhantomJS sees, because it could see a completely different page compared to what you see in your browser.

Comment: I just did that and the code is there (</tbody></table></div></div></a></td><td class="link ac"><a href="/germany/bundesliga/2016-2017/matches/17-1-20/sc-freiburg-vs-fc-bayern-munchen-h2h-stats">)
However, I just noticed, that in the <thead> is also a td with class name "link ac". But there is no link as a child, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: @I3LaCkPeArL try adding `//text()` to the end of the xpath, it seems that you are looking to select the text of your nodes rather than the nodes themselves.

Comment: That did not work, but I found a solution...I am a genius :D
Gonna post it here.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit trial and error, I found the following solution working for me.

```
//div[contains(@class,'right-body-2')]//tbody//td[contains(@class, 'link ac')]/a
```

and for output purposes I used

```
foreach (IWebElement match in matchLinks)
{
    rtb_matches.Text += match.GetAttribute("href") + Environment.NewLine;

}
```

I hope that this will help anyone with a similar problem, even though it is probably far from nice and pretty :D
Thank's to Granitosaurus for helping me :)